# Qt: Server should broadcast changing value and client should listen for it

Tags: c++, qt, client, qtcpserver

I wrote a program that calculates Pi. It approximates the digit positions after the 3.14 …

Now I want to know which position is calculated by my program currently. But I don't want to wait in front of the computer. Therefore I implement a QTcpServer and the possibility to access the server as client. The connection works fine. In the next step I would like to send the current value of Pi and the number of digits as broadcast via the server. Each time the client connects the server, the client should read these informations. The informations are updated continuously and the client should get these informations as long as he is connected. For updating the incoming information of the client I need some notification or polling functionality. How can I realize broadcast of the information (server) and the update notification (client).

header

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class HTTPServer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit HTTPServer(QObject *parent = 0);

    int value;

signals:

public slots:
    void newConnection();
    void readClient();

private:
    QTcpServer *server;
    QTcpSocket *socket;

};
```

cpp

```
#include "httpserver.h"

    HTTPServer::HTTPServer(QObject *parent) :
        QObject(parent)
    {
        server = new QTcpServer(this);

        connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(newConnection()));

        if(!server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 9999))
            qDebug() << "Server could not started!";
        else
            qDebug() << "Server started and listening ...";
    }

    void HTTPServer::calculate()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
            value = i;
    }

    void HTTPServer::newConnection()
    {
        socket = server->nextPendingConnection();

        socket->write("client connected\r\n");
        socket->flush();
        socket->waitForBytesWritten(3000);

        this->calculate();

        char buffer [50];
        sprintf(buffer, "%d\r\n", value);
        socket->write(buffer);
        socket->flush();
        socket->waitForBytesWritten(3000);

        connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readClient()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    }

    void HTTPServer::readClient()
    {
        QByteArray Data = socket->readAll();

        qDebug() << "Data in: " << Data;

        socket->write(Data);

        //if ((std::string stdString(Data.constData(), Data.length())) == "quitServer")
        //    server->close();
    }
```

`int value` should simulate the Pi value.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated] It's possible to do broadcasting with `QUdpSocket`. Qt SDK has great examples with [broadcasting implementation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-network.html)(Broadcast [receiver](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-broadcastreceiver.html) and [sender](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-broadcastsender.html) examples).

Also it's not possible to use TCP protocol for broadcasting.

Comment: Hi, thats what I am doing right now. But it's just done if the client connects the server. What I am searching for is an update feature. For each changed value the information should be broadcasted by the server and received by the client.

Comment: Ok thanks, think this will help me. But why it is not possible to send information over QTcpSocket? It already works with write and flush ... socket->write("client connected\r\n");

Comment: TCP protocol doesn't support broadcasting. It was designed not for this purposes.